# How to get rid of excel name cannot be the same name as a built-in name _FilterDatabase when opening a Excel file on Sharepoint?

Tags: microsoft-excel

We are working with Excel files on Sharepoint, I sync via Onedrive and open the files via Excel desktop app.

Quite often, when I open a file I get the error "Name cannot be the same name as a built-in name" referring to _FilterDatabase.

I then enter something and I am then able to open the workbook.

However, why does this happen, how can I get rid of it?

I already saw numerous solutions with Excel VBA to delete that - however that would mean converting the xlsx to xlsxm - which I am not allowed because it is a shared file.

Is there another way to get rid of that?

I remember in a different solution that a keycombination was pressed, a window opened with the _FilterDatabase entry, which was then deletable. But I do not remember the key combination anymore :(

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be related to the print area.

Goto **Formulas -> Namesmanager** and delete all entries with "*Printarea*" in it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).